# Highlighting Vim text with black background when ANSI colors are off

Tags: macos, vim, ansi-colors

I'm on OSX. I turned ANSI colors off in Terminal.app. This is great, but now visual selections are no longer highlighted. I'd like them to be simply inverted with a black background and white text. I've tried

```
hi Visual ctermfg=15 ctermbg=0
hi VisualNOS ctermfg=15 ctermbg=0
```

but nothing's happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm… this gives me an idea for a colorscheme. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without ANSI colors support there is no real point defining foreground and background colors.

What you are looking for is:

```
hi Visual cterm=reverse
hi VisualNOS cterm=underline
```

See `:help highlight-cterm`.